# Delete Selected Text from Textbox and Enter New Char in C#.NET

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to delete selected text from textbox and enter new character in place of it. 
For example, if textbox consists of `123456` and I select `345`, and press <kbd>r</kbd> on the keyboard, it should replace the selected text.

here is my code:

```
string _selectText = txtCal.SelectedText;
string _text = Convert.ToString(btn.Text);

if (_selectText.Length > 0) {
   int SelectionLenght = txtCal.SelectionLength;
   string SelectText = txtCal.Text.Substring(txtCal.SelectionStart, SelectionLenght);
   txtCal.Text = ReplaceMethod(SelectText, _text);
}

//replace method function
public string ReplaceMethod(string replaceString, string replaceText) {
   string newText = txtCal.Text.Replace(replaceString, replaceText);
   return newText;
}
```

Can anyone show me where my mistake is?

Comment: I am able to delete selected text but couldn't able to add new char in place of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextBox text "Replace" function does not work well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712740/textbox-text-replace-function-does-not-work-well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
if (textbox1.SelectedText.Length > 0)
{
   textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text.Replace(text1.Text.Substring(textbox1.SelectionStart, textbox1.SelectionLength), btn.Text);                
}
```

Comment: i think, I acted stupid here because I Exaggerated  my error so much that I could able to see minor error. Its working.

Comment: @Kundan Singh Chouhan: I am trying to replace 2nd occurrence of "aa" from "aaaabbbbcccc" with "r". By using above code it replace both "aaaa" with "rr". Can you help me with this.

Comment: @RushabhShah, do you mean to say "aa[aa]bbbbcccc" brackets words with "r"? so the result shoud be "aa[r]bbbbcccc" isn't it?

Comment: @RushabhShah, are you sure you are selecting only 2nd occurrence? if yes then the proble would be that the event on which you are executing this code is triggered multiple times.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan: Yes it is 2nd occurrence only. If you try to use other then "aa", "cc" then same things happen. What would be solution for that.

Comment: @RushabhShah, i guess the event on which you are executing this code is triggering multiple times.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan : can you suggest any solution for that.

Comment: @RushabhShah, can you provide me the code or files? So i can see where is the problem is?

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan: I have edited my original question with code

Comment: Consider the string "245657", select "5", this code will replace all occurrence of string "5" in the string "245657" so this code does NOT replace the selected text and does not answer the question

Answer (score 10):

The replace-based answer offered above may well replace the wrong instance of the selection, as noted in the comments. The following works off positions instead, and doesn't suffer that problem:

```
textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text.Substring(0, textbox1.SelectionStart) + textbox1.Text.Substring(textbox1.SelectionStart + textbox1.SelectionLength, textbox1.Text.Length - (textbox1.SelectionStart + textbox1.SelectedText.Length));
```

Comment: I think there is a lot of unnecessary code added to the end of the second substring call `, textbox1.Text.Length - (textbox1.SelectionStart + textbox1.SelectedText.Length));`.  Maybe try this instead? `textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text.Substring(0, textbox1.SelectionStart) + textbox1.Text.Substring(textbox1.SelectionStart + textbox1.SelectionLength);`

Answer (score 2):

The following does what you want and then selects the replacing text :)

```
    string _text = Convert.ToString(btn.Text);
    int iSelectionStart = txtCal.SelectionStart;
    string sBefore = txtCal.Text.Substring(0, iSelectionStart);
    string sAfter = txtCal.Text.Substring(iSelectionStart + txtCal.SelectionLength);
    txtCal.Text = sBefore + _text + sAfter;
    txtCal.SelectionStart = iSelectionStart;
    txtCal.SelectionLength = _text.Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same as other answers, but formatted differently using C# 6.0.

```
// If there is selected text, it will be removed before inserting new text.
// If there is no selected text, the new text is inserted at the caret index.
string before = textBox.Text.Substring(0, textBox.SelectionStart);
string after = textBox.Text.Substring(textBox.SelectionStart + textBox.SelectedText.Length);

textBox.Text = $"{before}{insertText}{after}";
textBox.CaretIndex = $"{before}{insertText}".Length;
```

Note that I set the `CaretIndex` to a new position *after* changing the text. This may be useful since the caret index resets to zero when changing the text like this. You may also want to focus the textbox to draw the user's attention to the change and allow them to know where the caret currently is.