# TextBox text "Replace" function does not work well

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have already looked at similar questions here but it did not help.

I am using windows forms. I have button1 and textbox1.

I am trying to replace (or delete) the selected text in textBox1 and enter new letter (letter A) in place of it.

The code works well with random mixed numbers and letters
for example:

> 385F1   select 8 and then result = 3A5F1  (8 replaced by A)
>
> H74S31B   select 4S and then the result is = H7A31B
>
> KQ5689   select Q5689 and then the result is KA

So it works well, but when I select a number or a letter from a string which consists of same numbers or letters then it does not work, for example:

> 666777222333  select any 7 then the result = 666AAA222333 (not
>   working)
>
> 9992244GG  select any 9 then the result = AAA2244GG (not working)
>
> QQQHHHUUU select any Q then the result = AAAHHHUUU (not working)
>
> QQQHHHUUU select any QH then the result = QQAHHUUU(it works when
>   different letters selected)
>
> 4433366 select 333 then the result = 44A66 (it works when all same
>   numbers is selected)

Hope I explained it well. I don't know what causes this behavior. please help. Thank you

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int TxTindex;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActiveControl = textBox1;
        textBox1.Focus();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Focus();

        if (textBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0) // to check if any text selected
        {
            TxTindex = textBox1.SelectionStart; // save the caret position 

            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(textBox1.Text.Substring(textBox1.SelectionStart, textBox1.SelectionLength),"A");

            textBox1.SelectionStart = TxTindex + 1; // place the caret after the inserted string
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `String.Replace` replaces *all* instances, not just one.  Why not just remove the selected characters using `String.Substring`?  Additionally, you could probably have Google searched this question...

Comment: @LukePark, same thing can be said of probably 90% of questions on SO. At this rate, and following your logic, they might as well shut the site down.

Comment: @LucMorin Except they might as well not shut the site down.  Stack Overflow is for **questions that don't already have answers**.  This question, with 100% certainty, already has an answer.  As new frameworks are released, standards changed, there will be questions that don't have answers.

Comment: @LukePark If question has already been answered on SO, then simply flag the question as a duplicate, and point to the existing answer. Your type of comment adds nothing of value.

Comment: @LucMorin You mean my comment that immediately helped out the OP even though I knew the question already had an answer?  Yeah I must be a real jerk.  If anyone's comment adds nothing of value, it's your original reply to me about *shutting the site down*.  Think about it.

Comment: @LukePark indeed, you are.

Comment: Luke Park . 1st: if you are a professional I am beginner and I am not waiting for you to tell me to google it, been looking for the answer around and no luck, this websit is my last resort so if I can't find an answer by myself then post it here. 2nd: I already  checked other posts. however, as  Luc Morin said: Your type of argument adds nothing of value.

Comment: If you read the *How do I ask a good question?* guide on StackOverflow, the very first bold term is **Search, and research**.  I'm not doing this to be mean, it's just how StackOverflow works.  The more people that know this, the better.  To both you and @LucMorin, if you don't like the rules, *don't play the game*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here :

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(textBox1.Text.Substring(textBox1.SelectionStart, textBox1.SelectionLength),"A");
```

The Substring function returns string. In your example (666777222333 select any 7 then the result = 666AAA222333 (not working)), it returns "7". But Text.Replace will replace all occurrences of 7. That is not what you want. What you can do is, instead of using `string.Replace` function, use `string.Remove` and `string.Insert`

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.SelectionStart, textBox1.SelectionLength).Insert(textBox1.SelectionStart, "A");
```

But this might not be very efficient for large strings. A `StringBuilder` would be better.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by the usage of `string.Replace` function.

What you are trying to accomplish can be done simply by

```
if (textBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
    textBox1.SelectedText = "A";
```

There is no need to save/set selection start.